# Why wont my sql query bring back the correct request?

Tags: php, mysql, video

I have a query that runs and gets all the information I need except the it wont execute the correct WHERE part. SO say if the id is checked on vid.php and then a query runs so that it can pull the info of a video like vides.id videos.name how can I make sure I only get 1 video but WHERE  videos.video_tag_id = category.video_tag ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1. code below.

NOTE: There are 2 tables (videos & category). I am trying to join both of them and pull out 1 video based on this query.

```
$categoryId = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id']:NULL);

if ($categoryId) {
       try {
            // select specific video based on category id
            $sql = "SELECT videos.id, videos.name, videos.video_src, videos.pLike, videos.video_tag_id, category.video_tag FROM videos,category WHERE videos.video_tag_id = category.video_tag ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
        //foreach for school
        $listCategoryVideo = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}else {
    echo "nope";
    die();
}//end if video catgeory was found and executed
```

so in the end someone clicks on a link sending them to vid.php?id=3.where everything is selected based on the id of 3 (category.video_tag) should be === to videos.video_tag_id and only choose 1 at random.

Comment: We'd need to see your table layout in order to answer the issue with the query - the PHP code only shows us how you are executing the query.

Comment: Yep we would need your tables to know exactly what's going on. But I think you're missing the comparison with the selected id. You're just joining all videos with their correct category but you're not restricting the result to `id=3`. Just add `and videos.video_tag_id= ". $categoryId . "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"`

Comment: Acutually@VerenaHaunschmid your suggestion did work thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `$categoryId` in your `SQL` query.

Please change

```
"... WHERE videos.video_tag_id = category.video_tag ..."
```

to

```
"... WHERE videos.video_tag_id = category.video_tag AND category.id = ".$categoryId." ..."
```

Maybe you have to set the correct field for your categoryId. In my example I used `category.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$sql = "SELECT videos.id, videos.name, videos.video_src, videos.pLike, videos.video_tag_id, category.video_tag FROM videos JOIN category ON videos.video_tag_id=category.video_tag ORDER BY videos.name ASC";
```